# how to insert text into mysql SELECT statement and display output in sentence?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tried this

```
select t1.name+' used '+t2.amount+' Credit' as History from table t2
  inner join table1 t1 on t1.userId=t2.userId order by t2.transaction_date DESC LIMIT 5;
```

And i am getting output as

[image]

but  i want output like this

[image]

How to get output like image2 using mysql select statement?

Comment: Use `CONCAT` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

Comment: Its better you do this in your application layer, from DB just collect your data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL does not use the `+` operator for sting concatenation.  Use `CONCAT` instead:

```
SELECT CONCAT(t1.name, ' used ', t2.amount, ' Credit') AS History
FROM table t2
INNER JOIN table1 t1
    ON t1.userId = t2.userId
ORDER BY t2.transaction_date DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

Using `+` for string concatenation looks like SQL Server syntax (and maybe a few other databases besides MySQL).  MySQL *can*, however, use the `||` for concatenation, if you set a certain mode:

```
SET sql_mode = PIPES_AS_CONCAT;
```

Then we could write the `SELECT` statement as:

```
SELECT t1.name || ' used ' || t2.amount || ' Credit' AS History
```

Answer (score 0):

i think best solution you can use  MySQL `CONCAT()` function is used to add two or more strings.