# How can I display data between specified dates and get a summation of only those data's?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, web

So I am using PHP and MySQL(PDO). I have a form that is a lot like the table image below in which the user is gonna input data (almost) every day.

**Data Entry Example:**

| Date | Old Case(1) | New Case(2) | Total Case(1+2) | Discharge | Conviction | Acquittal | Other |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12-06-2021 | 1000 | 500 | 1500 | 30 | 40 | 18 | 0 |
| 13-06-2021 | 1500 | 200 | 1700 | 10 | 14 | 23 | 9 |
| 14-06-2021 | 1700 | 100 | 1800 | 19 | 33 | 23 | 18 |
| 15-06-2021 | 1800 | 200 | 2000 | 32 | 18 | 07 | 21 |

And later maybe he would want to get the total number of data between two specified dates which the user would specify.Here is also another question of mine. How will the user specify the dates?. for example, he would select the 'from' date"01-January-2021" and the 'to' date "01-February-2021" after selection he would enter submit button, and then there would be a table shown in the website like below where the total "Discharge" number, total "Conviction", total "Acquittal" and total "Others" numbers between those dates would show.

**Final Output:**

| Date(Between Two Dates) | Last Entry Old Case in Date Range(1) | Last Entry New Case in Daterange(2) | Total Case(1+2) | Total Discharge | Total Conviction | Total Acquittal | Total Other |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12-6-2021 to 15-6-2021 | 1800 | 200 | 2000 | 91 | 105 | 71 | 48 |

Now how can I do this function? I am not being able to figure out the function where all the data between selected dates would get total up according to their fields and then display the totaled results! Do I need to use Ajax?

DB-FIDDLE(I have never used this before so don't really know how to use it properly.): https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/goPRNPA8Q6QRkn258sdrsd/1

**Another Question:** I thought I would be able to figure this issue on my own but I couldn't after trying the whole day. So There are three other columns in my database (after updating the colums). They are "Old Case", "New Case" and the total of these two columns "Total Cases". This "Total Case" becomes the "Old Case" for the next entry or date. And in my Final Output, It would show the last entered "Old Case" and "New Case" between the selected "DateRange". But I am not being able to figure out how I can implement this. Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: This seems like more of a SQL question. But we can't see your database table structure or any sample data, so it's hard to answer. AJAX is optional here, it's just helps you avoid refreshing the page, it has nothing to do with how to query the data

Comment: @Adyson thank you for your reply. I have updated my question with the table structure. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: And the sample data? An exact example of the desired output would also be very helpful. Also please paste all such info as text, not pictures, otherwise we cannot easily use it to test potential answers etc. Same for the table structure too, please. If you feel like making a DbFiddle that would be even more helpful. Make it as easy as possible for the volunteers here to assist you. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson I have edited my post again according to the way you asked. Sorry I never used DbFiddle so I don't know how it actually works but still, I have tried. Hope that is how it is supposed to be used! Also thank you for your assistance! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL (I assume you have an auto increment ID column in your table so that we could relate the previous record with the current record);

```
SELECT          CONCAT(MIN(M.Date), ' to ', MAX(M.Date)) AS DateRange, 
                SUM(M.Discharge) AS TotalDischarge, 
                SUM(M.Conviction) AS TotalConviction, 
                SUM(M.Acquittal) AS TotalAcquittal, 
                SUM(M.Other) AS TotalOther, 
                M.NewCase AS LastNewCase, 
                MP.NewCase AS LastOldCase
FROM            tmp_mytable AS M
    LEFT JOIN   tmp_mytable AS MP ON MP.ID = (SELECT MAX(M2.ID) FROM tmp_mytable AS M2)
WHERE           M.Date BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-02-01'
```

I think you wanted to select the records before '2021-02-01', not up to '2021-02-01'. In that case, change the WHERE clause as following

```
WHERE           M.Date >= '2021-01-01' 
    AND         M.Date < '2021-02-01'
```

Code example: PHP: My.PHP

```
print "
    <form action=\"./My.PHP\" method=\"POST\">
        Date: 
        From <input type=\"date\" name=\"DateFrom\" required>
        To <input type=\"date\" name=\"DateTo\" required>
        <button type=\"submit\" name=\"btnPost\">Post</button>
    </form>
";

$Recordset = $HTML = [];

if(isset($_POST["btnPost"])){
    $Database = new PDO("Database", "User", "Password");

    $Query = $Database->prepare("
        SELECT          CONCAT(MIN(M.Date), ' to ', MAX(M.Date)) AS DateRange, 
                        SUM(M.Discharge) AS TotalDischarge, 
                        SUM(M.Conviction) AS TotalConviction, 
                        SUM(M.Acquittal) AS TotalAcquittal, 
                        SUM(M.Other) AS TotalOther, 
                        M.NewCase AS LastNewCase, 
                        MP.NewCase AS LastOldCase
        FROM            tmp_mytable AS M
            LEFT JOIN   tmp_mytable AS MP ON MP.ID = (SELECT MAX(M2.ID) FROM tmp_mytable AS M2)
        WHERE           M.Date BETWEEN '{$_POST["DateFrom"]}' AND '{$_POST["DateTo"]}'
    ");

    $Query->execute();
    $Recordset = $Query->fetchAll();
}

foreach($Recordset as $Record){
    $HTML[] = "
        <tr>
            <td>{$Record["DateRange"]}</td>
            <td>{$Record["TotalDischarge"]}</td>
            <td>{$Record["TotalConviction"]}</td>
            <td>{$Record["TotalAcquittal"]}</td>
            <td>{$Record["TotalOther"]}</td>
            <td>{$Record["LastNewCase"]}</td>
            <td>{$Record["LastOldCase"]}</td>
        </tr>
    ";
}

print "
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Discharge</th>
                <th>Conviction</th>
                <th>Acquittal</th>
                <th>Other</th>
                <th>New</th>
                <th>Old</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>" . implode(null, $HTML) . "</tbody>
    </table>
";
```

Comment: would it be possible to use concat() to create a new column (for the date to date output) and group by the new column? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50698830/12181863

Comment: I don't think you can do that for SUM. You could do that if you wanted the COUNT of records.

Comment: @Broken Arrow Thank You for your reply. For the dates well I wanted the user to select a ‘from date’ and a ‘to date’ from a datepicker or something  and according to the selected dates the sun would happen of all the datas between those two dates!

Comment: @RxN Understood, that is why I posted two versions of the WHERE clause. Use the BETWEEN one in this case.

Comment: @YHStan Yes you can do that if you want multiple summary row per date range. However, in that case, I would rather depend on DATE_FORMAT() function for GROUP BY clause instead of going with a new column.

Comment: Oh I see. How do you think I should make the user select the ‘from’ and ‘to’ dates? And use it with the SQL query? Can you maybe give an code example?

Comment: is that so? i figured using using concat to add the new column in a subquery then using group by on the external query would work to give a final output of only one row @BrokenArrow

Comment: @YHStan I am open to learning ways :) I appreciate your enlightenment.

Comment: nah, i m just fresh out of a mysql course last semester. i m just here to learn more

Comment: @Broken Arrow Thanks, Man! You Are An Absolute Life Saver! But You see I am facing another issue regarding this same function. Can You Please check my Updated Question and help me if you can? It would be really helpful for me! also point to be noted apart from PHP I also use HTML as my main website structure. So example using HTML and PHP would be helpful. Thanks and again sorry for asking so much.

Comment: @RxN It is possible to aggregate the previous NewCase as OldCase for current data range, but there are logical challenges here, this is no PHP/HTML case. You need to carefully set your mind up how you want to determine the term against the logic. Also, when you say previous NewCase becomes the OldCase, you need to determine how much in the back date you want to evaluate as your previous numbers. I know this is difficult to understand here. but you you may try with a sub query to fetch the aggregation data for that purpose.

Comment: @RxN It is our choice how we mix up PHP/HTML in our scripts, I personally go for inline HTML, but most of the world goes with inline PHP (then again inline HTML within that inline PHP). It is your choice how you manage this. I have always found inline HTML is more manageable when I imagine me a PHP developer, again, it is your choice. I would ask you to imagine yourself be the PHP interpreter and how would you find yourself translating the code looking at the code, PHP interpreter will feel the same.

Comment: I have update the answer to calculate (somehow) the OldCase and NewCase totals. I assume you have an auto increment ID column to your database so we could relate the previous record against the current row, otherwise it won't work. Also, the SUM of NewCase & OldCase may not reflect the numbers as you expect, it is a business logical issue, not a PHP/SQL implementation issue.

Comment: @Broken Arrow Thank You For Your Help. But The Code Didn't show me my expected result. It was showing me the summation of all the data of "New Case" and "Old Case" where I just want the last Entered "New Case" and "Old Case" Data Between the daterange. Also  I do have an auto-increment ID column to your database.

Comment: The edited SQL might get you what you mention. As told before, this is a business logic issue you want to implement in SQL, not a code issue. You may want to play with your SQL in MySQL Workbench before you go for the code.

Comment: @Broken Arrow Ok, Bro. Anyways Thank You For Your Support! Also, I noticed that you are also from Bangladesh which I wasn't expecting at all. Anyways Thanks!